# reduce lists given single value of 2d lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, graph-theory

I have 2 lists:

```
edges = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]]
weight = [10,8,7,3,7]
```

edges represents the list of edges connecting 2 nodes together with the corresponding weight.

for the given starting nodes as in edges[i][0] I want to choose the shortest connecting point given the weight so in this case the result would look like:

```
connect = [[0,3],[1,2]]
weight = [7,3]
```

Because out of all the nodes connected to 0 3 is the closest one and for 1, 2 is the closest one.

I am not able to formulate the problem, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would a library like networkx help your case?

Comment: This is URL for the networkx fuction https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length

Answer (score 0):

```
edges = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]]
weight = [10,8,7,3,7]

connect = []
wght = []

In [8]: for i in set(e[0] for e in edges):
...:     temp = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(edges, weight) if a[0] == i]
...:     temp = min(temp, key=lambda x: x[1])
...:     connect += [temp[0]]
...:     wght += [temp[1]]

In [9]: connect
Out[9]: [[0, 3], [1, 2]]

In [10]: wght
Out[10]: [7, 3]
```

In case you are into one liner:

```
In [20]: [min([(a, b) for a, b in zip(edges, weight) if a[0] == i], key=lambda x: x[1]) fo
...: r i in set([e[0] for e in edges])]
Out[20]: [([0, 3], 7), ([1, 2], 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, columns=['start','end'])
df['weight'] = weight
df.loc[df.groupby('start')['weight'].idxmin()]
```

With the results being:

```
start   end weight
0       3   7
1       2   3
```